# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

Tags: python, python-requests

I get the "requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))" error in python on a script that works perfectly on my friend's laptop. Basically there is a server on raspberry pi3 and he gets replies perfectly well, but my python seems to crash upon receiving a reply. Doesn't seem to be only python's fault, because curl also doesn't get a response. In both cases the server says that it got the request and sent 200 OK.

Comment: Impossible to answer without a [mcve]. At the very least, a client MCVE, server MCVE and a sniffer session capture are required to get an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, SelfEd! As @ivan_pozdeev stated in the previous comment, please provide the relevant snippets of your code to help us answer your question. If you're not sure what's relevant, try to create a minimal program that leads to the same result. Often, you will stumble upon the solution while doing this.

Comment: Use a sniffer to see what's happening at network level and localize the problem -- find out whether the server, the client or the network connectivity/configuration is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Bitdefender was silently dropping all incoming traffic. The solution was to just turn off Bitdefender